# Unity iOS Build Error regarding Cocoapods and Firebase/Messaging

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

This error shows whenever i build my Unity project to iOS. Did i missed something?

iOS framework addition failed due to a Cocoapods installation failure. This will likely result in a non-functional Xcode project.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Firebase/Messaging (= 4.0.2)` required by `Podfile`

Specs satisfying the `Firebase/Messaging (= 4.0.2)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

im using Unity 2017.1.0f3

Comment: Tried to changed my Target minimum iOS version to 8.0 but still getting the same Error

Answer (score 0):

> Specs satisfying the Firebase/Messaging (= 4.0.2) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

This message is telling you that you need to rise minimum iOS version to resolve dependancy

Comment: hello, tried it in unity Player settings -> Target minimum iOS version to 8.0 to 10 but i still get the Error. is there some settings you recommend?